# What is the music in the 'Dazed and Confused' mission in Far Cry 4?

Tags: far-cry-4, game-music-identification

I've just been playing the Dazed and Confused level and was wondering what the music was. It's a mission with Yogi and Reggie done under the influence of drugs.

I was curious if it was a normal track or something written for *Far Cry 4*. I've tried googling for it but as there's a Led Zeppelin song of the same name it's a bit difficult to find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes from *Far Cry 4*'s [wiki page](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Cry_4):

**Akasha - "Hippy Sh*t"** (Plays throughout Yogi and Reggie's missions)